# Java Echo Server Not Working

Tags: java, sockets

Server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class EcServer{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4019);
        Socket so=ss.accept();
        PrintStream pw=new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream());
        String str;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
        while(true)
        {
            str=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client Input : "+str);
            pw.println(str);
            if(str.equals("."))
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class EcClient{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        Socket so=new Socket("localhost",4019);
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
        String str;
        str=br.readLine();
        while(!str.equals("."))
        {
            ps.println(str);
            str=br1.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);
            str=br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code has 2 parts : the client and server . I m quite new to Java Socket Programming  .

The server has a server socket and a socket type . The message is sent to the server from the client via the 4019 port . The server just prints the same message as a output and a copy is sent back to the client server.

The clients job is to take a line and send it to the server which will return a copy of the message and print its output.

The program terminates when "." is encountered.

The problem is that when i type a message and send , both the client and serve hang.

Answer (score 1):

You are not flushing your output stream and that is the reason your server and clients are hanging. Either use `ps.flush();` after writing anything to socket or use auto flushing by:

```
PrintStream pw=new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream(), true);
```

and

```
PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream(), true);
```

on both the ends. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your client code like this and it will not terminated.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Socket so = new Socket("localhost", 25101);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                so.getInputStream()));
        String str;
        str = br.readLine();
        while (true) {
            ps.println(str);
            str = br1.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);
            if ( str.equals(".") )
                break;
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        so.close();
    }
}
```

I have change your port number for my testing but revert it back